# Android Thread hangs in Release mode but Runs in Debug Mode

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging, release

I am trying to run a manager in background thread in my game application.
I am using the following runnable class to enable an object for a while.

```
class ShowDialogRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Context context;
    private static final float DCOUNTER = 3000;
    ShowDialogRunnable(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Resourses.getInstance(context).showDialog = true;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis()-st <= DCOUNTER){
          //  LoggerCommon.logMessageConditional("RUNNABLE", true, LogMessageType.DEBUG, "Loging", "waiting for "+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-st)+"    "+st);

        }
        Resourses.getInstance(context).showDialog = false;
        Resourses.getInstance(context).selC = 0;
    }
}
```

and I am calling it by :

```
new Thread(new ShowDialogRunnable(context)).start();
```

and waiting for the thread to finish in the main UI thread

```
while (res.showDialog){

        }
```

Now this runs perfectly when I am running in debug mode from Android studio. But when I am trying to run the release apk its hanging in that runnable's while loop.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you could un-comment your log statement.  Also make it un-conditional.  After you do this, post the output.

Comment: I put it to see whats going on. it goes till 3000 and then stops

Comment: If I enable debugging in release apk that also works. But I can't put it in Playstore, and without debugging mode its hanging.

Comment: Given that the output stops after 3000ms, how did you conclude that the code is "hanging in that runnable's while loop".

Comment: Also, looping is a very inefficient way to pause.  You should use Thread.sleep(3000) instead.

Comment: Try using the Thread.sleep approach and see if that changes anything.

Comment: no code after that while loop is executing. I gave debug outputs after that too.

Comment: Another big problem with this code is that you are pausing the UI thread.  That is a big no-no in Android.  I suggest you implement your thread using a subclass of AsyncTask.  AsyncTasks will notify the UI thread with their work is done. It is a very standard, clean, approach to this very problem in Android.

Comment: It is also possible that the problem lies in your resource class which appears to be a singleton you are using to store state.  This is also a very dangerous thing to do in Android.  So again, I very strongly recommend just using an AsyncTask rather that a home-grown approach.

Comment: I had a similar problem I could never solve - a signed apk always hung on a certain while loop while an unsigned apk worked perfectly. It made no sense. Sure you can do it a different way but I never figured out *why* this was happening.

Comment: Well, I had to work around to get it work.
Apparently Thread or AsyncTask didn't help me as my thread should work for the entire session. I guess Android does't support that in release mode.
But if anyone can solve this please let me know. would like to know.